# Is there software to contract word combinations?

Tags: string

I think it's a common situation when one needs to contract certain phrases to make identifiers, preserving the original sense. Is there a software/algorithms to facilitate it?

I have a hundred word combinations each around 20 characters long which I want to turn into no-more-than-12-character-long identifiers.

An example:

```
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT -> CUSTOMER_ACC
or even
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT -> CUST_ACC
```

Comment: Will [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) work for you? If you have a hash table you can always get back to the phrase.

Comment: @oleksii Oops, I think I misunderstood the "one hundred" from the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution A** 
Do it manually, load your words into any text processing editor, run Find-And-Replace with your words, for example:

- Find: `CUSTOMER`
- Replace with: `CUST`

It is human readable but requires manual work.

---

**Solution B**
Use hashtable:

```
HASH | PHRASE
------------------------------
hash1| CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT
hash2| CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_CREDIT
```

Hash function will be unique and you can tailor its length, the problem is, it is not human-readable.

---

**Solution C** 
If you store this somewhere (db, xml, etc.) you can have a structure like

```
metacode
struct
{
   GUID id;
   string Name;
}
```

Each phrase has its own unique id and the text. Internally you use GUID, but for display purposes you use text representation.